# Bash terminal windows and tabs take a few seconds to start

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, bash, migration-assistant

The problem appeared after using the Migration Assistant.

Edit: There is no command in Preferences>Profiles>Shell. 
Both .profile and .bashrc are empty. Putting `set -x` at the beginning didn't help me understand. Here is the output:

`++ shell_session_history_check
++ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
++ SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK=1
++ shell_session_history_allowed
++ '[' -n /Users/User/.bash_history ']'
++ local allowed=0
++ shopt -q histappend
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ allowed=1
++ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
++ return 0
++ shell_session_history_enable
++ umask 077
++ /usr/bin/touch /Users/User/.bash_sessions/686FA199-70DE-46D7-8F02-B57AD1B17598.historynew
++ HISTFILE=/Users/User/.bash_sessions/686FA199-70DE-46D7-8F02-B57AD1B17598.historynew
++ SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
++ '[' 'shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd' = shell_session_history_check ']'
++ [[ shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd =~ (.*)(; *shell_session_history_check *| *shell_session_history_check *; *)(.*) ]]
++ PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=k
++ [[ k =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=k
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=w
++ [[ w =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=w
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=z
++ [[ z =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=z
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=k
++ [[ k =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=k
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ ch=i
++ [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=i
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 15 ))
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://Mac/Users/User`

Edit: Inspecting what files are sourced, I found /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal

```
    # bash support for Terminal.


# Working Directory
#
# Tell the terminal about the current working directory at each prompt.

if [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
    # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL, including
    # the host name to disambiguate local vs. remote paths.

    # Percent-encode the pathname.
    local url_path=''
    {
        # Use LC_CTYPE=C to process text byte-by-byte. Ensure that
        # LC_ALL isn't set, so it doesn't interfere.
        local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#PWD}; ++i)); do
        ch="${PWD:i:1}"
        if [[ "$ch" =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]; then
            url_path+="$ch"
        else
            printf -v hexch "%02X" "'$ch"
            # printf treats values greater than 127 as
            # negative and pads with "FF", so truncate.
            url_path+="%${hexch: -2:2}"
        fi
        done
    }

    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "file://$HOSTNAME$url_path"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd${PROMPT_COMMAND:+; $PROMPT_COMMAND}"
fi


# Resume Support: Save/Restore Shell State
#
# Terminal assigns each terminal session a unique identifier and
# communicates it via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable so that
# programs running in a terminal can save/restore application-specific
# state when quitting and restarting Terminal with Resume enabled.
#
# The following code defines a shell save/restore mechanism. Users can
# add custom state by defining a shell_session_save_user_state function
# that writes restoration commands to the session file at exit. e.g.,
# to save a variable:
#
#   shell_session_save_user_state() { echo MY_VAR="'$MY_VAR'" >> "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"; }
#
# During shell startup the session file is executed. Old files are
# periodically deleted.
#
# The default behavior arranges to save and restore the bash command
# history independently for each restored terminal session. It also
# merges commands into the global history for new sessions. Because
# of this it is recommended that you set HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE to
# larger values.
#
# You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting
# SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 0. There are some common user customizations
# that arrange to share new commands among running shells by
# manipulating the history at each prompt, and they typically include
# 'shopt -s histappend'; therefore, if the histappend shell option is
# enabled, per-session history is disabled by default. You may
# explicitly enable it by setting SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 1.
#
# The implementation of per-session command histories in combination
# with a shared global command history is incompatible with the
# HISTTIMEFORMAT variable--the timestamps are applied inconsistently
# to different parts of the history; therefore, if HISTTIMEFORMAT is
# defined, per-session history is disabled by default.
#
# Note that this uses PROMPT_COMMAND to enable per-session history
# the first time for each new session. If you customize PROMPT_COMMAND
# be sure to include the previous value. e.g.,
#
#   PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }your_code_here"
#
# Otherwise, the per-session history won't take effect until the first
# restore.
#
# The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:
#
#   ~/.bash_sessions_disable

if [ ${SHELL_SESSION_DID_INIT:-0} -eq 0 ] && [ -n "$TERM_SESSION_ID" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.bash_sessions_disable" ]; then

    # Do not perform this setup more than once (which shouldn't occur
    # unless the user's ~/.bash_profile executes /etc/profile, which
    # is normally redundant).
    SHELL_SESSION_DID_INIT=1

    # Set up the session directory/file.
    SHELL_SESSION_DIR="$HOME/.bash_sessions"
    SHELL_SESSION_FILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID.session"
    mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"

    #
    # Restore previous session state.
    #

    if [ -r "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" ]; then
    . "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"
    rm "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"
    fi

    #
    # Note: Use absolute paths to invoke commands in the exit code and
    # anything else that runs after user startup files, because the
    # search path may have been modified.
    #

    #
    # Arrange for per-session shell command history.
    #

    shell_session_history_allowed() {
    # Return whether per-session history should be enabled.
    if [ -n "$HISTFILE" ]; then
        # If this defaults to off, leave it unset so that we can
        # check again later. If it defaults to on, make it stick.
        local allowed=0
        if shopt -q histappend || [ -n "$HISTTIMEFORMAT" ]; then
        allowed=${SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY:-0}
        else
        allowed=${SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY:=1}
        fi
        if [ $allowed -eq 1 ]; then
        return 0
        fi
    fi
    return 1
    }

    if [ ${SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY:-1} -eq 1 ]; then
    SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID.history"
    SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID.historynew"
    SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED="$HISTFILE"

    shell_session_history_enable() {
        (umask 077; /usr/bin/touch "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW")
        HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW"
        SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
    }

    # If the session history already exists and isn't empty, start
    # using it now; otherwise, we'll use the shared history until
    # we've determined whether users have enabled/disabled this.
    if [ -s "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE" ]; then
        history -r "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE"
        shell_session_history_enable
    else
        # At the first prompt, check whether per-session history should
        # be enabled. Delaying until after user scripts have run allows
        # users to opt in or out. If this doesn't get executed (because
        # the user has replaced PROMPT_COMMAND instead of concatenating
        # it), we'll check at shell exit; that works, but doesn't start
        # the per-session history until the first restore.

        shell_session_history_check() {
        if [ ${SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK:-0} -eq 0 ]; then
            SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK=1
            if shell_session_history_allowed; then
            shell_session_history_enable
            fi
            # Remove this check if we can; otherwise, we rely on the
            # variable above to prevent checking more than once.
            if [ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" = "shell_session_history_check" ]; then
            unset PROMPT_COMMAND
            elif [[ $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ (.*)(; *shell_session_history_check *| *shell_session_history_check *; *)(.*) ]]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
            fi
        fi
        }
        PROMPT_COMMAND="shell_session_history_check${PROMPT_COMMAND:+; $PROMPT_COMMAND}"
    fi

    shell_session_save_history() {
        # Save new history to an intermediate file so we can copy it.
        shell_session_history_enable
        history -a
        # If the session history doesn't exist yet, copy the shared history.
        if [ -f "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED" ] && [ ! -s "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE" ]; then
        echo -ne '\n...copying shared history...'
        (umask 077; /bin/cp "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED" "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE")
        fi
        # Save new history to the per-session and shared files.
        echo -ne '\n...saving history...'
        (umask 077; /bin/cat "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW" >> "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED")
        (umask 077; /bin/cat "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW" >> "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE")
        : >| "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW"
        # If there is a history file size limit, apply it to the files.
        if [ -n "$HISTFILESIZE" ]; then
        echo -n 'truncating history files...'
        HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED"
        HISTFILESIZE="$HISTFILESIZE"
        HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE"
        HISTFILESIZE="$size"
        HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW"
        fi
        echo -ne '\n...'
    }
    fi

    #
    # Arrange to save session state when exiting the shell.
    #

    shell_session_save() {
    # Save the current state.
    if [ -n "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" ]; then
        echo -n 'Saving session...'
        (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
        declare -F shell_session_save_user_state >/dev/null && shell_session_save_user_state
        shell_session_history_allowed && shell_session_save_history
        echo 'completed.'
    fi
    }

    # Delete old session files. (Not more than once a day.)
    SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/_expiration_check_timestamp"
    shell_session_delete_expired() {
    if ([ ! -e "$SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE" ] || [ -z "$(/usr/bin/find "$SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE" -mtime -1d)" ]); then
        local expiration_lock_file="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/_expiration_lockfile"
        if /usr/bin/shlock -f "$expiration_lock_file" -p $$; then
        echo -n 'Deleting expired sessions...'
        local delete_count=$(/usr/bin/find "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR" -type f -mtime +2w -print -delete | /usr/bin/wc -l)
        [ "$delete_count" -gt 0 ] && echo $delete_count' completed.' || echo 'none found.'
        (umask 077; /usr/bin/touch "$SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE")
        /bin/rm "$expiration_lock_file"
        fi
    fi
    }

    # Update saved session state when exiting.
    shell_session_update() {
    shell_session_save && shell_session_delete_expired
    }
    trap shell_session_update EXIT
fi
```

Comment: It kind of sounds like what is described in https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6270 -- check if anything in your shell's profile scripts uses `makewhatis` -- you make need to follow all the breadcrumbs to see what files are sourced.

Comment: The only file I suspect is /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal. Let me copy its content in my original message

Comment: I sourced the file /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal manually using "time source /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal" and it completed in 0m0.003s, so no problem here.

Comment: Could you check under Preferences>Profiles>Shell if a command is set to run when Terminal is launched? To find out whether a command in your startup files is slowing Terminal down, add `set -x` to the beginning of your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do for more information), open a tab and check the output. As a reference: I have a **huge** `.bashrc` file and Terminal needs about two seconds to display the prompt.

Comment: @jaume Both files are empty. Putting `set -x` at the beginning didn't help me. I will add  the output to my original post.

Comment: @jaume There is no command in Preferences>Profiles>Shell

Comment: Just for me to better understand your issue: does Terminal launch slowly (that is, it bounces for a few seconds in the Dock) or does Terminal start in a snap and it takes a few seconds for you to see the shell prompt?

Comment: It is the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Catalina. Problem solved.